# how to make the ocean not flat

Tags: ocean-simulation

[image]

I wanna make the ocean not flat, it's like the real ocean had a surface and seabed, I keep searching for the tutorial but I don't find any.

Answer (score 0):

Blender has great tool exactly for your purpose called Ocean Modifier:

Just add it to a plane:

[image: ocean modifier]

Adjust some settings and insert keyframes to time value:

[image]

Comment: no, it's like when you make a cube and then the surface is the wave and the seabed it's just water slow and smooth, you know something like that. sorry if I pronounce it wrong...

Comment: You can convert tuned modifier to mesh by applying it. Please attach some reference to your answer.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBnAH.gif like that

Comment: you need animated or statics mesh? different ways of complexity..